# How to trigger a click on a link(for modal) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I  am from TW, and my English is not good ..

I use this modal plugin:  http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/

The plugin have to action with the href.   I try to talk - -

**I have 2 questions**

1. I can't use $("#ex1").modal() or $("#ex1").modal('show') to show
   my dialog -  it has to link with a  example:

   ```
   <a href-"#ex1" rel="modal:open">xxx</a>
   ```

   so i tried

   ```
   $("#myid a").trigger('click'),
   ```

   but cant action. how to action the a function....  Of course i can use
   CSS to make tag a like a button , but I cant close the #ex1 and open    #ex2

   ```
   <a href-"#ex1" rel="modal:open">xxx</a> --open      <a href-"#ex1" rel="modal:close">xxx</a>--close)
   ```
2. How to use the way like $("#ex1").mydal('open') or something to
   open my dialog ?

Off course there are so money plugin like this . but this plugin is most sample and cant change my theme or screen...

thx all    (OMG poor Eng..)

Comment: Please ask one question per, um, question!

Comment: Have you tried: `var $my_modal = $("#ex1").modal(); $my_modal.open();`

Comment: yes, i already tried it . error , and i try agein .. 

 
$("#ex3").open()
VM9018:2 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionVM9018:2 
$("#ex3").modal()
VM9019:2 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say you can't use:

```
$('#ex1').modal();
```

Because it does open the div with `id="ex1"` as a modal.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/or4y8quy/)

---

If you do have an `<a>` element with `href="#ex1"` and `rel="modal:open"`, you can also programmatically open the modal with:

```
$('#ex1Link').trigger('click');
```

(Where `ex1Link` is the `id` value of the `<a>` element.)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7w0nqpc/)

---

In case you are not properly including the libraries, which would cause the `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error you are getting, here is a complete page. Just make sure the `jquery.modal.js` and `jquery.modal.css` files are in the same directory as this page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Modal</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.modal.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.modal.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#openBtn').click(function() {
        $('#ex1').modal();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ex1" style="display: none;">
<p>Thanks for clicking. <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a> or press ESC</p>
</div>
<p><button type="button" id="openBtn">OPEN</button></p>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: $('#ex1').modal() cant run. $('#ex1Link').trigger('click')  just show the Dom on the Console, the dialog still hidden  , like this
  
$('#aaa').trigger('click');
[<a id=​"aaa" href=​"#ex2" rel=​"modal:​open">​User Login​</a>​]

Comment: @chenchinchi - I suspect you are not properly including the jQuery and jQuery Modal libraries. You need to include them both, and you need to include jQuery first and then jQuery Modal. I have added to my answer.